# Equal Column Heights Bootstrap 4 in Nested columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a simple 3-column content section in Bootstrap 4. The background color of the whole section is light gray. So, to separate the columns, I had to nest them. You can see it here: [Code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/alemieux/pen/OBjbBX)

```
<div class="related-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" pardot-region="related-content-title">
                <h4 class="black">Related Content</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <img class="feature"
                     src="https://go.nielsen.com/l/271912/2018-10-08/chwkd/271912/63689/article_photo.png"
                     alt="Asian family" pardot-region="article-image" pardot-region-type="image"/>
                <div class="col-md-12 related-pod" pardot-region="related-article">
                    <h4><a href="#">Fan Favorite: Radio listeners spend 58% of their tune-in time with their favorite
                            station</a></h4>
                    <p>Americans spend 87% of their AM/FM radio listening tuning into their three favorite stations.
                        What&rsquo;s more interesting is that 58% of all listening goes to just one station, the
                        listener&rsquo;s favorite.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Read More &gt;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <img class="feature"
                     src="https://go.nielsen.com/l/271912/2018-10-08/chwkn/271912/63699/report_photo.png" alt="Reports"
                     pardot-region="report-image" pardot-region-type="image"/>
                <div class="col-md-12 related-pod" pardot-region="related-report">
                    <h4><a href="#">2016 Social Media Report</a></h4>
                    <p>There&rsquo;s no denying the massive impact of social media, but the way people connect&mdash;with
                        content, brands and each other&mdash;is evolving.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Read More &gt;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <img class="feature"
                     src="https://go.nielsen.com/l/271912/2018-10-08/chwkl/271912/63695/podcast_photo.png"
                     alt="Database Podcast" pardot-region="media-image" pardot-region-type="image"/>
                <div class="col-md-12 related-pod" pardot-region="related-media">
                    <h4><a href="#">The Database, Episode 1: Holiday creep is extending the holiday shopping season</a>
                    </h4>
                    <p>Why are consumers starting their holiday shopping sooner? It turns out it&rsquo;s part of a
                        phenomenon called &#8220;holiday creep,&#8221; a new podcast from Nielsen dives into this trend
                        and holiday retail 2017.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Read More &gt;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see that the middle column is shorter than the others. How do I get the nested columns to be equal heights? I've tried putting an explicit height in the stylesheet, but that's not responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something different but it's the result that you want

```
<div class="related-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" pardot-region="related-content-title">
                        <h4 class="black">Related Content</h4>
                    </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 dienst-kaart">
                    <div class="dienst">
                        <div class="row no-gutter">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <img class="diensten-icon img-fluid" src="https://go.nielsen.com/l/271912/2018-10-08/chwkl/271912/63695/podcast_photo.png" alt="Web-design-Icon">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                    <h2>The Database, Episode 1: Holiday creep is extending the holiday shopping season</h2>
                                    <p>Why are consumers starting their holiday shopping sooner? It turns out it&rsquo;s part of a phenomenon called &#8220;holiday creep,&#8221; a new podcast from Nielsen dives into this trend and holiday retail 2017.</p>
                                <p><a href="#">Read More &gt;</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 dienst-kaart">
                        <div class="dienst">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <img class="diensten-icon img-fluid" src="https://go.nielsen.com/l/271912/2018-10-08/chwkl/271912/63695/podcast_photo.png" alt="Web-design-Icon">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                        <h2>The Database, Episode 1: Holiday creep is extending the holiday shopping season</h2>
                                        <p>There’s no denying the massive impact of social media, but the way people connect—with content, brands and each other—is evolving..</p>
                                    <p><a href="#">Read More &gt;</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 dienst-kaart">
                            <div class="dienst">
                                <div class="row no-gutter">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <img class="diensten-icon img-fluid" src="https://go.nielsen.com/l/271912/2018-10-08/chwkl/271912/63695/podcast_photo.png" alt="Web-design-Icon">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                            <h2>The Database, Episode 1: Holiday creep is extending the holiday shopping season</h2>
                                            <p>Why are consumers starting their holiday shopping sooner? It turns out it&rsquo;s part of a phenomenon called &#8220;holiday creep,&#8221; a new podcast from Nielsen dives into this trend and holiday retail 2017.</p>
                                        <p><a href="#">Read More &gt;</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
    .related-content {
    padding-top: 1.25em;
    padding-bottom: 9em;
    background-color: #f7f8f9;
}
.related-content h4 {
padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: .5em;
color: #333;
}
.dienst-kaart{
display: flex;
padding:15px;
min-height:100%;
background: #eee;
}
.dienst {
background:white;
padding:4%;
opacity:0.9;
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/jnliana/pen/mzMKGd?editors=1100)

Comment: Can I suggest that for those that are not intimately familiar with html and css, adding a bit of an explanation as to how this works would change it from a good answer to an outstanding one.

Comment: Yes, min-height does seem to do the trick. I wasn't familiar with row no-gutter. Thanks!